# UK student visa, no sponsor, possible?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm currently trying to apply for a visa to United Kingdom. The aim of my trip is a short English language course (15 days). The type of visa I'm trying to apply for is a short-term study visa.

However, when I was filling out the visa application on their official site, I noticed there's a *required* field about sponsorship. The problem is, I support myself and no one sponsors me for the trip.

The question is, did I choose the wrong type of visa? Or am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find the answer. Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's in the guidance, read here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visa-refusal to see why it's important to study the guidance.

Comment: A visitor visa allows you to study for up to 1 month

Comment: You can go there for only 6 month

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** keep in mind that receiving any advice regarding visas from a non-official source (such as myself and, presumably, most people on this website) is speculation at best. If you are uncertain, contacting an embassy and/or the company providing the course is highly recommended.

That said, *sponsorship* probably doesn't refer to financial sponsorship, but rather a so-called sponsor license that your course provider must possess. To quote the [Eligibility](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/eligibility) page from the official website:

> You must be accepted on a course with an education provider that holds a Tier 4 sponsor licence.

On the same website, you can find a complete [list of registered sponsors](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-students) and a list of educational institutions that are exceptions to this rule.

In short, it's perfectly OK that you're supporting yourself (as long as you can provide bank statements or other evidence that you can), but it's highly recommended that you contact your course provider for help regarding the sponsorship related fields.

Answer (score 3):

For a fifteen day course, you may be able to get away without a student visa. A visitor visa allows you to study for up to 30 days as long *as it is not the main purpose of your visit*. If you were to combine your course with some tourism, you might be able to get a visitor visa.

Comment: +1 for identifying the preferred and low-risk strategy